# What current methods for statistical disclosure limitation are best trade-offs between data privacy and data utility?

Tags: dataset, survey, differential-privacy

In many situations raw microdata is not released by institutions due to privacy preserving. Many techniques are used for protecting sensitive values in data. But many of them can destroy multivariate structures in data and data itself is then not suitable for research at all. On the other hand, if data is not protected adequately, privacy preserving may not be assured.

Therefore, any trade-off between privacy preserving and utility of data is desired. What methods are most popular for this purpose and attempt not to destroy multivariate structure of data while preserving privacy as much as possible?

Comment: This seems like a very open-ended question and the best approach might depend on the research goal. Do you have a particular one in mind?

Comment: Our [Fifth Cross Validated Journal Club](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/949/930) (Nov. 2011) may be of interest.

Comment: @MattKrause, I have no special goal in mind, but we can restrict this question to multiple regression and factor analysis which I am interested the most.